# Иероглифы в ответе на get запрос

Tags: python, парсер

Прошу помочь, ранее парсил через личный кабинет и при запросе цены по артикулу было все нормально, возвращался ответ с наименованием, с ценой и наличием. Сейчас, видимо, обнаружили, что парсил и возвращаются в ответе иероглифы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать, чтобы декодировать эти символы в кириллицу? Код для парсинга если что сам допишу, мне бы тут понять что делать с иероглифами. Сам новичок в этом, если не хватает каких то еще скринов, прошу написать, добавлю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так у вас "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" может это упакованный ответ пришёл

Comment: Разобрались в итоге то или нет?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но пока так и не разобрался, пока разбираюсь, временно написал другой парсер, используя pyautogui